# TypeScript union as function parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have an app where I use a json structure to define the columns of a table.

Each column has a `key` and `label` property and an optional `transformFunc` property that takes a function that transforms the data to be displayed in the column.

This is the type for `Column`:

```
type Column = {
  key: string
  label: string
  transformFunc?: (value: string | number | Date) => string
};
```

`transformFunc` either takes a `string`, `number` or `Date` as an argument.
However, I'm not able to properly type it this way:

```
const col: Column = {
  key: 'date',
  label: 'Date',
  transformFunc: (value: string) => value.substring(0, 5)  // TS2322: Type '(value: string) => string' is not assignable to type '(value: string | number | Date) => string'
}
```

How can I solve this?

I looked into generics but I don't see how to do this.

Comment: One way is to typecast it like - `transformFunc: (value) => (value as string).substring(0, 5)`

Answer (score 4):

In generic way

```
type Column<T extends string | number | Date> = {
  key: string
  label: string
  transformFunc?: (value: T) => string
};

const col: Column<string> = {
  key: 'date',
  label: 'Date',
  transformFunc: (value) => value.substring(0, 5)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After defining `Column`, you could had no need for any type when using it. You just use values, like `'date'` and `'Date'`, give to `transformFunc` a function without any type, then use type narrowing to have what you want. Something like the below code.

> See this TypeScript [playgroud](https://www.typescriptlang.org/pt/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwK4FsB2UC8UDeBYAKCigGsIQAuKAZ2ACcBLNAc0OIQEMAjCBK2xizZR6HNNQBmcOigBiSNAGMA-FQAUANw7II-ek2ZQAPlDSoedY1AAiHYBACUWAHw19QggF8A3IUKK4cWAoAL5YRFQMbHwiUnIqAHIAEzsIBIAaYU4eMITbewzhUXEpGXkldS0dJ0xXHAYJKDVQSDhGqqRoTGwAIgEDHqccOghgJDoMDogAOmokLn6WNQAGdKgAVgdPXmpoEbGJqB6ez2IAejOoABUAZQAmAGY7u6or8GgEzW1OvUFmGtci2YCSgDGopjgwQ41GoDGYaG4CGgwDgIneUE+U1+BisZhQFis+UcLjcfwShE8QA) I created.

```
type Column = {
  key: string
  label: string
  transformFunc?: (value: string | number | Date) => string
};

const col: Column = {
  key: 'date',
  label: 'Date',
  transformFunc: (value) => {if (typeof value == "string") {return value.substring(0, 5)}else return ""} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of your type definition, a `transformFunc` must accept all of the union's type, so you can't create a Column with a `transformFunc` accepting just one.

If you know what type of data a specific column will hold, you can use a type assertion in your function:

```
const col: Column = {
  key: 'date',
  label: 'Date',
  transformFunc: (value: string | number | Date) =>
    (value as string).substring(0, 5)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you don't want to use a generic, the union should instead be outside of the function scope

```js
type Column = {
  key: string
  label: string
  transformFunc?: 
    ((value: string) => string) | 
    ((value: number) => string) | 
    ((value: Date) => string)
};

const col: Column = {
  key: 'date',
  label: 'Date',
  transformFunc: (value: string) => value.substring(0, 5)
}
```

Or if you want to infer the type based on the value of transformFunc you can use a helper function

```
type ColumnGeneric<T extends string | number | Date> = {
  key: string
  label: string
  transformFunc?: (value: string | number | Date) => string
}

const columnInferenceBuilder = <
  _ extends ColumnGeneric<FunctionProp>, 
  FunctionProp extends string | number | Date
>(o: {
  key: string;
  label: string;
  transformFunc: (value: FunctionProp) => string
}) => o

const inferredColumn = columnInferenceBuilder({
  key: 'date',
  label: 'Date',
  transformFunc: (value: string) => 'foobar',
})
```

This pattern might be more useful if you had an extra property of `value` that corresponds to the transformFunc arguments (or somehow related otherwise to discriminate with)

```js
// imagine its imported
const importedData = {
  key: 'foo',
  label: 'Foo',
  value: 0
} as const

const inferredColumn2 = columnInferenceBuilder2({
  ...importedData,
  transformFunc: (value) => 'foobar',
  //   ^? (value: 0) => string
})
```

[View these examples on TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NnKBvm)